# Task: I am trying to create a pandas dataframe from a list of dictionaries. Problem: This creates a dataframe for each dictionary item

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a dataframe from three lists which I have generated using webscraped data. However, when I try and turn these lists into dictionaries and then use them to build my pandas dataframe it outputs a dataframe for each dictionary item (row) rather than one dataframe including all of these items as rows within the dataframe.

I believe the issue lies in the for loop that I have used to webscrape the data. I know similar questions have been asked on this one, including here [Pandas DataFrame created for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53512489/pandas-dataframe-created-for-each-row) and here [Take multiple lists into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522724/take-multiple-lists-into-dataframe) but I have tried the solutions without any joy. I believe the webscrape loop adds a nuance that makes this more tricky.

Step by step walkthrough of my code and the output are below, for reference I have imported pandas as pd and bs4.

```
    # Step 1 create a webscraper which takes three sets of data (price, bedrooms and bathrooms) from a website and populate into three separate lists

for container in containers:
    try:
        price_container=container.find("a",{"class":"listing-price text-price"})
        price_strip=price_container.text.strip()
        price_list=[]
        price_list.append(price_strip)

    except TypeError:
        continue

    try:
        bedroom_container = container.find("span",{"class":"icon num-beds"})
        bedroom_strip=(bedroom_container["title"])
        bedroom_list=[]
        bedroom_list.append(bedroom_strip)
    
     except TypeError:
        continue

    try:
        bathroom_container=container.find("span", {"class":"icon num-baths"})
        bathroom_strip=(bathroom_container["title"])
        bathroom_list=[]
        bathroom_list.append(bathroom_strip)
    
    except TypeError:
        continue

# Step 2 create a dictionary 

    data = {'price':price_list, 'bedrooms':bedroom_list, 'bathrooms':bathrooms_list}


# Step 3 turn it into a pandas dataframe and print the output

    d=pd.DataFrame(data)
    print(d)
```

This gives me a dataframe for each dictionary as below.

```
   price               bedrooms          bathrooms                                   
0  £200,000            3                 2

[1 rows x 3 columns]
  

   price               bedrooms          bathrooms                                   
0  £400,000            5                 3

[1 rows x 3 columns]


   prices              bedrooms          bathrooms                                   
0  £900,000            6                 4

[1 rows x 3 columns]

and so on.....
```

I've tried dictionary comprehension and list comprehension, to give me one dataframe rather than a dataframe for each dictionary item:

```
data = [({'price':price, 'bedrooms':bedrooms, 'bathrooms':bathrooms}) for item in container]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

and, despite how I do the list expression, this yields an even weirder output. It gives me a dataframe for each item in the dictionary with the same row of information repeated a number of times

```
   price               bedrooms          bathrooms                                  
0  £200,000            3                 2
0  £200,000            3                 2
0  £200,000            3                 2

[3 rows x 3 columns]
  

   price               bedrooms          bathrooms                                   
0  £400,000            5                 3
0  £400,000            5                 3
0  £400,000            5                 3

[3 rows x 3 columns]


   price               bedrooms          bathrooms                                   
0  £900,000            6                 4
0  £900,000            6                 4
0  £900,000            6                 4
[1 rows x 3 columns]

and so on...
```

How do I resolve this problem and get all of my data into one pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should do `price_list=[]` and `bedroom_list=[]` and `bathroom_list=[]` before your `for` loop - otherwise they were 1-element long at most as it in every turn they would be reseted to `[]` then appended with single element. Secondly if you wish to have single dataframe you should create it outside `for` loop i.e. dedent `data = {'price':price_list, 'bedrooms':bedroom_list, 'bathrooms':bathrooms_list}`
and following lines. Finally in case of missing data you should denote it - if any but first `continue` will be executed your `price_list`, `bedroom_list`, `bathroom_list` will have different lengths. I suggest replacing first `continue` using `price_list.append(None)` second using `bedroom_list.append(None)` third using `bathroom_list.append(None)`, so you would have clear indication in your dataframe where data is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The code part you're testing here is good- a dictionary of lists will always return a single dataframe. So this part:

```
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

can't be the cause of the problem. Instead, it's the fact that it's buried inside a loop, so is running three times. The same goes for your lists which are being defined over and over again.

Take those parts out of the loop, and you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You have to merge the three lists

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["price"] + data["bedrooms"] + data["bathrooms"] )
```

if you want something more generic :

```
list_ = [item for i in data for item in data[i]]
df = pd.DataFrame(list_)
```